# cvs to javascript remove first row?

Tags: javascript

I have a cvs file like this:

```
Month, 2005, 2006
jan, 50,67
feb, 40,78
mar, 60,70
apr, 64,60
may, 70,66
june, 80,77
july, 90,80
aug, 86,89
sep, 80,99
oct, 76,90
nov, 70,80
dec, 55,77
```

I want to get the first row out and only use the data for second row and after. My code can only get data extract data by column. Can someone show me how to get the first row out?

```
var lines = data.split('\n');
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
            var items = line.split(',');
            //get first column
            c.push(items[0]);
            //get second column
            d.push(parseInt(items[1]));
            //get 3rd column
            e.push(parseInt(items[2]));
```

Thanks you

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+remove+first+array+element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Array.prototype.shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) method.

```
// removes the first item (the first row) from the array and returns it
var removedRow = lines.shift();
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) removes the first item of an array:

```
var lines = data.split('\n');
lines.shift();
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
  // ...
```

Alternatively you can use [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var lines = data.split('\n').slice(1);
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
  // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm frequently API-dyslexic (was it shift or unshift? slice or splice?) I have been known to do the following:

```
var lines = data.split('\n').reverse();
var heading = lines.pop();
lines.reverse();
```